# Send data between Android and Mac OS X

Tags: android, objective-c, macos, bluetooth, connection

I try to connect my android phone to my mac OSX via Bluetooth and exchange data (to start: an integer). I have already made ​​a connection between two android that are able to send and receive data. So I have the android code to have a server machine and a client machine. I try to do the same with a computer (Mac OSX) and android. 
All the android code is done in Java and all the OSX code would be objective C. 
I already watch "https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX/BT_Bluetooth_On_MOSX.html" with IOBluetooth but this has not helped me too... 
I also found CBCentralManager and CBPeripheral but with this, my android does not detect either my mac ...

The main problem is the connection part with the mac.

Is it possible to make a bluetooth exchange between mac and android (by code)? 
If yes, how?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is it necessary to use bluetooth? You would be able to do this using a web service, instead.

Comment: For my tests, it would be better by bluetooth